# Making Apache faster by adjusting KeepAlive, MaxClients and AllowOverride

Tags: apache, configuration, clients

I'm trying to configure apache to react faster. Currently I experience heavy lags and huge response times. When I googled for answers, there were articles mentioning `KeepAlive`, `MaxClients` and `AllowOverride` so my focus is on them for now, I guess. I just don't seem to find them.

Here is a the `phpinfo();` output:

```
apache2handler
**************
Apache Version          Apache/2.4.12 (Win64) PHP/5.6.8
Apache API Version      20120211
Server Administrator    admin@example.com
Hostname:Port   
Max Requests            Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts                Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server          No
Server Root             C:/Apache24
Loaded Modules          core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat
mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file
mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi
mod_dir mod_env mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5
mod_rewrite mod_setenvif
Directive               Local Value     Master Value
engine                  1               1
last_modified           0               0
xbithack                0               0
```

Maybe somebody can explain this output to me? I particular:

1. "`Timeouts`" = "`Connection: 60`" setting
2. "`Per Child`" =  "`0`" setting

   If I understand this right:

   - there are 60 connections to be allowed
     simultaneously
   - every connection has a maximum of 100 requests (why
     so many?)
   - the server allows a client to load all the ressources
     in one request for 5 seconds
3. maybe those settings are to be found in httpd.conf and not in php.ini? (right now I don't have access to those files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the Timeouts relates to how longer the server will wait for connection, with 60 seconds being the default.

The Per Child bit has to do with how many threads your running per child process.

I'm a bit vague on this stuff but have a read through the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html) and you should find all the explainations you need!